# Is there a way to import a varible from a list made by another python script?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am pushing a file via FTP to cameras. I want to input ips into my script, which then creates a list, and then opens a new cmd prompt for each ip entered and does the specified commands to successfully push the file to multiple ips at the same time (each in their own cmd prompt)

My push script works if I run it as a standalone. I can get the primary file to gather ips into a list and then open them one at a time to push the configs to each cameras solo (so it will eventually do all the ips 1 at a time). I tried setting up a python script that calls a windows batch file which then calls the script to run but i couldnt get this to work due to not being able to read the list from the main file. I'm also tried to import f1 into Firmware, like you would a module, but it pulls the entire file in and that just creates more cmd prompts and continues the cycle of not doing anything but making popups

f1.py

```
import subprocess, os

xlist = []
while True:
 x = str(input('What Ips Are We Upgrading? '))
 if x == "":
  break
 elif x not in xlist:
  xlist.append(x)

alist = xlist

for ip in alist:
 subprocess.Popen("start cmd /K Firmware.py ", shell=True)
```

Firmware.py

```
import time
import keyboard



keyboard.write("ftp " + ip)
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.write("root")
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
keyboard.write("pass")
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
keyboard.write("bin")
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
keyboard.write("hash")
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
keyboard.write("put 1.bin flash")
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
```

I'm expecting it to open 1 cmd prompt for each input and do the steps from Firmware.py
However, I keep getting errors that 'ip' is not defined (from Firmware.py) or it will iterate through the list but only one ip at a time and then when thats finished it'll do another (but just one at time)

Answer (score 0):

To pass the IP-address to the second script, you should add it to the command-line of the `firmware.py` script. Then you can access it through `sys.argv`.

```
for ip in alist:
    subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'Firmware.py', str(ip)])
```

In `Firmware.py`, the IP address should then be in `sys.argv[1]`.

If you want to use FTP, why not use the [`ftplib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)? That is probably a lot easier than launching a separate script to talk to an FTP program.

```
from ftplib import FTP

# Create FTP instance and log in
ftp = FTP(host=ip, user='root', passwd='pass')
ftp.transfercmd('put 1.bin flash')
# or maybe ftp.storbinary? Haven't used manual FTP in years...
```

In the end, the speed of the FTP transfers will be limited by the bandwidth of the network to the camera's. So I'm not sure if it is worthwhile to launch many processes at the same time. In any case, if you want to do that, the `concurrent.futures` module could help.